# Backbone - changing root for http/url requests (but not for backbone routes)

Tags: backbone.js, trigger.io, backbone-routing

I have an web app that I am transiting into a trigger.io application.

I am trying to get it to work as a single page app, and currently, it is fraught with issues.

One of my issues right now is that this is how we set the url for api calls:

```
Muse.prototype.url = function() {
  return "/answers/" + this.id + ".json";
};
```

Obviously, it will use the root (localhost) and call

```
http://localhost:3000/answers/slug
```

But since it is a single file, it calls

```
file:///file_path/answers/slug
```

Which would obviously fail.

How do I get it to use a root of my definition WITHOUT changing the root of the backbone routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override [sync method](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync):

```
var sync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    options.beforeSend = function (jqXHR, settings) {
        settings.url = 'http://localhost:3000' + settings.url;
    };
    return sync(method, model, options);
};
```